# UIGestureRecognizer under the other UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I couldn't find a solution for my small problem with Gestures and hierarchy. There you have how it is looks like:

```
-superview
--view A
---objectViewA z UIGestureRecognizer
--view B
---objectViewB z UIGestureRecognizer
```

On the beginning viewA and viewB are hidden. User unhide it as he wants. When the viewB is not covering viewA I can move objectViewA but if we will unhide viewB I can move objectViewB but objectViewA doesn't return any touch.

I added `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` delegate but it doesn't work. It didn't get any action.

How to fix this problem? I will be glad!

Comment: what would you like to do, when `objectViewB`'s `UIGestureRecognizer` is called with `objectViewA `?

Comment: `objectViewA` and `objectViewB` could be move around the screen but `objectViewA` is under the `viewB`. I want that all objects A and B could be moving around

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to determine if viewB should handle the gesture or pass it down the hierarchy to viewA.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate

Comment: I have all gesture delegates in superview. Unfortunately objectViewA doesn't react on any touch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the delegate method like this.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

       if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:(Your View)]) {
             return YES;
          }
          return NO;
   }
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Background gesture doesn't receive any touch :/